# Error: Invalid initialization of non-const reference of type '.. &' from a temporary of type '...*const'

Tags: c++, windows, operator-overloading

I've been searching the internet and asking my friends for an answer for a good hour to help me with this tiny little error in my code.
This is what I try to run:

```
BinStabloMapa<string,string> m;
string s1("Sarajevo"), s2("Zagreb");
m[s1] = "BiH";
m[s2] = "Hrvatska";
{
    BinStabloMapa<string,string> m2(m);
    BinStabloMapa<string,string> m3;
    m3=m;
    m.obrisi(s1);

    cout << m2.brojElemenata() << " ";
    cout << m2[s1] << " ";
    cout << m3.brojElemenata() << " ";
    cout << m3[s1] << " ";
}

cout << m.brojElemenata();
cout << " '" << m[s1] << "' ";
m.obrisi();
cout << m.brojElemenata();
cout << " '" << m[s2] << "'";
```

And this is the error:
    `error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'BinStabloMapa< >&' from a temporary of type 'BinStabloMapa< >* const'|`

It shows the error in my operator =:

```
template <typename TipKljuca,typename TipVrijednosti>
BinStabloMapa<TipKljuca,TipVrijednosti>& BinStabloMapa<TipKljuca,TipVrijednosti>::operator =(const BinStabloMapa<TipKljuca,TipVrijednosti> &m)
{
    if(this==&m) return this;    // ERROR APPEARS HERE 

    obrisiPomocna(korijen);
    korijen=0;

    kopiraj(korijen, m.korijen, 0);
    return *this;
}
```

I'm not quite sure what am I doing wrong here, since I've been taught to make the operator = like this: the protection of self-destrcution + the destructor + the copy constructor.
The code that I'm trying to run should be able to compile, since it's the autotest for my whole program.
Sorry if I didn't explained it too well, still learning C++ and all the english terms :)

Comment: Should this be tagged `windows`? It's often good to provide such information, but I don't see how it applies.

Comment: You've got two return statements in that function, and one's not throwing that error. What's your conclusion?

Comment: I had a guy in my last question telling me that I should tag the operating system, but I'll untag it if it doesn't fit.
Oh my God, I just added a '*' infront of 'this' in my 1st return and now it's good. How did I not see this :O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `return this` to `return *this`.